# How to calculate time taken for request to be served in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I want to calculate the time taken by application to serve a particular request. i.e.. difference between the time the request comes to the server and time the server responded with response back

In c#, we have something called Global.ascx in which we have the functions like `Application_BeginRequest` and `Application_EndRequest` which can be used for this purpose.

Similarly does rails contains these types of functions where I can record the request timings?

Comment: The way to handle this in Rails or any type of Rack server is through the use of middleware that wraps the request. There are already serveral profilers like [rack-mini-profiler](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler) and adapters for stuff like New Relic though so you don't need to reinvent the wheel. https://scoutapm.com/blog/which-rails-profiler-is-right-for-you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails will by default log the time taken to serve each request. These logs go to the console and `log/development.log` if you're running a development server, and to wherever you have your production logs configured to go in production mode.

You're looking for a line that reads something like:

```
Completed 200 OK in 16ms (Views: 6.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)
```

If you need to measure something more granular than the entire request you could start with the guide on instrumentation: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_instrumentation.html#process-action-action-controller.

Answer (score -1):

There is a module call [Benchmark](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) in ruby for this.

For example,

```
def your_action_to_measure
  time = Benchmark.measure do
    #Your code here
  end
  puts time # => This will print the time in server.
end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: While this would be  helpful for benchmarking a single method or piece of code I don't see how its relevant to profiling an entire Rails application.